# Multiplying a numpy array within Psychopy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, psychopy

**TL;DR: Can I multiply a numpy.average by 2? If yes, how?**

For an orientation discrimination experiment, during which people respond on how well they're able to discriminate the angle between an visible grating and non-visible reference grating, I want to calculate the Just Noticeable Difference (JND).

At the end of the code I have this:

```
#write JND to logfile (average of last 10 reversals)
if len(staircase[stairnum].reversalIntensities) < 10:
    dataFile.write('JND = %.3f\n' % numpy.average(staircase[stairnum].reversalIntensities))
else:
   dataFile.write('JND = %.3f\n' % numpy.average(staircase[stairnum].reversalIntensities[-10:]))
```

This is where the JND is written to the file, and I thought it'd be easy to multiply that "numpy.average" line by 2, which doesn't work. I thought of making two different variables that contained the same array, and using numpy.sum to add them together.

```
 #Possible solution
 x=numpy.average(staircase[stairnum].reversalIntensities[-10:]))
 y=numpy.average(staircase[stairnum].reversalIntensities[-10:]))
 numpy.sum(x,y, [et cetera])
```

I am sure the procedure is very simple, but my current capabilities of programming are limited and the psychopy and python reference materials did not provide what I was looking for (if there is, please share!).

Comment: Please post the original code that did not work and the error message or wrong result you got. If possible, create a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have tried `numpy.average(....) * 2`, haven't you? (Or `x + y` instead of `numpy.sum` in the attempted solution?)

Comment: Adding to kazemakase's comment: pay attention to existing parenthesis and think about other binary operators which may need you to introduce additional parenthesis to get the correct order of evaluation when putting the `* 2` into the expression.